# Div not showing up in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I noticed that my div for my navigation is not displaying in Safari but is showing up in every other browser. It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. I've tried using @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and !important but those don't seem to work. My site is http://www.sanforddesigns.com. Any help, that would be great!

```
<div class="fixed"> 
    <div class="nav_container">
        <a id="logoBtn"><img src="_images/logo.png" height="86" width="86" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a id="webdesign1Btn" href="#webdesign_one">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a id="photoBtn" href="#photography">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a id="resumeBtn" href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a id="aboutBtn" href="#aboutMe">About</a></li>
          <li><a id="contactBtn" href="#contactMe">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

.nav_container {
margin-top:0px;
background: #f2f2f2;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;  
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display: none` in your media query at line 1547 is kicking in for some reason even on large screens. Perhaps validate your CSS, or try adding `and` after `screen`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I was working on some media queries from earlier and I forgot I had those in there. Totally makes sense! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Your media query syntax is invalid. You have a media query on line 1539 of `style.css` as follows:

```
@media only screen (max-width: 480px) {
```

So you're missing an `and` between the `screen` and `(max-width[..]`. So it should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

Some browsers, like Chrome, will accommodate these mistakes, but Safari is a bit more strict, so the `.nav_container { display: none }` that's inside that media query is taking effect in all versions of Safari instead of only on small screens.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Yup! This was the problem! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: No problem - apparently I type slower than Ralph :)